# Trying to install a package from bullseye-backports

Tags: debian, apt, backports

I am running Debian Bullseye and I want to install ffmpeg 4.4.1, which looks to be [available in sid](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ffmpeg):
[image]

So I have added the [backports repo](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/):

```
# apt-cache policy
Package files:
...
 500 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.2,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu
 100 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=bullseye-backports,n=bullseye-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
...

# apt-get install -t bullseye-backports ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:4.3.3-0+deb11u1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
```

`apt-cache show ffmpeg` only shows one entry, which is for ffmpeg 4.3 in the main stable repository.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems ffmpeg-4.4.1 is not in bullseye [backports](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ffmpeg). If you really want to use 4.4.1, you'd have to add debian testing repos, but **[don't do this lightheartedly](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#What_are_some_best_practices_for_testing.2Fsid_users.3F)**!